# Removing an unknown blank area in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have two pages on my website. I tried to make it so that they had the same appearance but they do not.
This page has a blank area at top of page. Please, show me how to remove it. I cannot find what HTML code is causing this blank area.

http://ec2-50-17-62-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com/dev/chia-se-dia-diem

This page is normal without unexpected blank area
http://ec2-50-17-62-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com/dev

Thank You!

Comment: Try removing margin and padding from your body styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget to close any tag in your site. Most probably it is problem of javascript.   so, remove one by one javascript and check this out...

Comment: It works when i remove file css bootstrap.min.css. It overrided css of form. I deleted this line form{margin:0 0 20px;} in file bootstrap.min.css. It works fine :)